# consequence of axiom of regularity

Tags: solution-verification, set-theory

I want to prove that for every non-empty set $A$ is the case that $A\notin A$. This is what I did:

Let $A$ be a set such that $A\neq\emptyset$ and $A\in A$. $\{A\}$ is a set since $A$ is a set. $\{A\}\neq\emptyset$ (since $A\in\{A\}$) and in consequence, by the axiom of regularity, exists a set in $\{A\}$ such that its intersection with $\{A\}$ is empty. $A$ is the only set in $\{A\}$, so that $\{A\}\cap A=\emptyset$; $A\in A$ implies $\{A\}\cap A\neq\emptyset$, but this is absurd. Therefore, for every non-empty set $A$ is the case that $A\notin A$.

Is my proof correct?

If this is not, please don't tell me why is wrong, only tell me if it is wrong or not. Thank you so much.

Comment: Yea it's fine, although I'd say that since this is such an elementary proof, I'd suggest being very explicit about the results used to make each derivation. I.e., the use of axiom of pairing to justify $\{A\}$ being a set.

Comment: There’s no reason to require $A$ is nonempty. (In that case the contradiction would appear much sooner, but there’s no reason to split off that case in the first place.)